# Should fsync be used after each fclose?

Tags: c, linux, file, stdio

On a Linux (Ubuntu Platform) device I use a file to save mission critical data.

From time to time (once in about 10,000 cases), the file gets corrupted for unspecified reasons.
In particular, the file is truncated (instead of some kbyte it has only about 100 bytes).

Now, in the sequence of the software

1. the file is opened,
2. modified and
3. closed.

Immediately after that, the file might be opened again (4), and something else is being done.

Up to now I didn't notice, that `fflush` (which is called upon `fclose`) doesn't write to the file system, but only to an intermediate buffer. Could it be, that the time between 3) and 4) is too short and the change from 2) is not yet written to disc, so when I reopen with 4) I get a truncated file which, when it is closed again leads to permanent loss of those data?

Should I use `fsync()` in that case after each file write?

What do I have to consider for power outages? It is not unlikely that the data corruption is related to power down.

Comment: Can you not open, modify, write to temp file, close, flush, delete original, (or move to backup folder), rename?

Comment: Also, make sure you are checking the return value from `fclose()`.  Since it implicitly calls `fflush()` to write data, it can fail just like any of the stdio calls that write data can fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fwrite` is writing to an internal buffer first, then sometimes (at `fflush` or `fclose` or when the buffer is full) calling the OS function `write`.

The OS is also doing some buffering and writes to the device might get delayed.

`fsync` is assuring that the OS is writing its buffers to the device.

In your case where you open-write-close you don't need to `fsync`. The OS knows which parts of the file are not yet written to the device. So if a second process wants to read the file the OS knows that it has the file content in memory and will not read the file content from the device.

Of course when thinking about power outage it might (depending on the circumstances) be a good idea to `fsync` to be sure that the file content is written to the device (which as Andrew points out, does not necessarily mean that the content is written to disc, because the device itself might do buffering).

Comment: *`fsync` to be sure that the file content is written to disc.*  But that just means the disk *device* (whatever it might be - a RAID controller or an actual disk) has accepted the data.  That doesn't mean the data is safely stored - disk devices cache data in memory, too.

Answer (score 4):

> Up to now I didn't notice, that fflush (which is called upon fclose) doesn't write to the file system, but only in an intermediate buffer. Could it be, that the time between 3) and 4) is too short and the change from 2) is not yet written to disc, so when I reopen with 4) I get a truncated file which, when it is closed again leads to permanent loss of those data?

No. A system that behaved that way would be unusable.

> Should I use fsync() in that case after each file write?

No, that will just slow things down.

> What do I have to consider for power outtages? It is not unlikeley, that the data corruption is related to power down.

Use a filesystem that's resistant to such corruption. Possibly even consider using a safer modification algorithm such as writing out a new version of the file with a different name, syncing, and then renaming it on top of the existing file.

Comment: 'safer modification algorithm' - yes, that's exactly what I would do.

Answer (score 3):

If what you're doing is something like this:

```
FILE *f = fopen("filename", "w");
while(...) {
    fwrite(data, n, m, f);
}
fclose(f);
```

Then what can happen is that another process can open the file while it's being written (between the `open` and `write` system calls that the C library runs behind the scenes, or between separate `write` calls). Then they would see only a partially written file.

The workaround to that is to write the file with another name, and `rename()` it over the actual filename. The downside is that you need double the amount of space.

If you are sure the opening of the file happens only *after* the write, then that cannot happen. But then there has to be some syncronization between the writer and reader so that the latter does not start reading too early.

`fsync()` tells the system to write the changes to the actual storage, which is a bit of an oddball within the other POSIX system calls, since I think nothing is specified of a system if it crashes, and that's the only situation where it matters if some data is stored on the actual storage, and not in some cache. Even with `fsync()` it's still possible for the storage hardware to cache the data, or for an unrelated corruption to trash the file system when the system crashes.

If you're happy to let the OS do its job, and don't need to think about crashes, you can ignore `fsync()` completely and just let the data be written when the OS sees fit. If you *do* care about crashes, you have to look more closely into what guarantees the filesystem makes (or doesn't). E.g. at least at some point, the `ext*` developers pretty much demanded applications to do an `fsync()` on the containing directory, too.

Comment: fflush is part of the c stream library. He is using fopen fclose, not open close.

Comment: @RobertJacobs, it doesn't matter, the C library is going to have to call `write()` at some point, when closing the file at the latest. Anyway, edited to show the stdio calls.